# Very Slow Update despite Indexing MSSQL 2005

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, indexing

EDIT:
We're in the process of moving server and I've just tested this on the new server. There's no performance problem there. This seems to be down to an underpowered, badly organised server.

One of our processes suddenly ran very slowly last night. The slow step was tracked down to an update statement on a table that was admittedly not too cleverly indexed.

So today I've added indexes to all the tables involved, but I'm still getting terrible performance.
I really don't understand it - possibly I'm still doing something less than smart. 
Any suggestions welcomed.

update is as follows:

```
update test_HDM_RTT
set patient_district_no = b.legacy_number
from test_HDM_RTT a
inner join PHD.migration.PatScope b
on a.patient_pas_no = b.TrustNumber
```

patscope is 2474147 rows, test_hdm_rtt is 815278

definition of tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test_HDM_RTT](
    [pk_episode_id] [int] NULL,
    [pk_event_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [activity_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [activity_datetime] [datetime] NULL,
    [activity_subtype1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [activity_subtype1_code] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [activity_subtype2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [activity_subtype2_code] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [activity_type] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [activity_type_code] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [clock_start_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [clock_stop_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [dir_code] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [div_code] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [episode_id_ext] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [episode_id_appt] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [episode_id_ref] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [episode_id_ref_medway] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [episode_id_wl] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [erod] [datetime] NULL,
    [nhs_number] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [patient_id] [int] NULL,
    [patient_district_no] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [patient_pas_no] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [pathway_id] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [pct_code] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [ref_source_code] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [rtt_episode_id] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [rtt_outcome_code] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [rtt_outcome_desc] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [rtt_start_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [rtt_start_ind] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [rtt_stop_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [site_code] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [spec_natcode] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [spec_pascode] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [transfer_text] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [op_rtt_count] [int] NULL,
    [app_rec_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [cons_code] [varchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO


USE [PIP]
/****** Object:  Index [pk_event_id_clustered]    Script Date: 03/06/2013 14:46:52 ******/
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [pk_event_id_clustered] ON [dbo].[test_HDM_RTT] 
(
    [pk_event_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


USE [PIP]
/****** Object:  Index [idx_episode_id_appt]    Script Date: 03/06/2013 14:46:52 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_episode_id_appt] ON [dbo].[test_HDM_RTT] 
(
    [episode_id_appt] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


USE [PIP]
/****** Object:  Index [idx_episode_id_ref]    Script Date: 03/06/2013 14:46:52 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_episode_id_ref] ON [dbo].[test_HDM_RTT] 
(
    [episode_id_ref] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


USE [PIP]
/****** Object:  Index [idx_episode_id_wl]    Script Date: 03/06/2013 14:46:52 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_episode_id_wl] ON [dbo].[test_HDM_RTT] 
(
    [episode_id_wl] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


USE [PIP]
/****** Object:  Index [patient_pas_no]    Script Date: 03/06/2013 14:46:52 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [patient_pas_no] ON [dbo].[test_HDM_RTT] 
(
    [patient_pas_no] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

and

```
USE [PHD]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [migration].[PatScope]    Script Date: 03/06/2013 14:47:57 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [migration].[PatScope](
    [RID] [varchar](7) NOT NULL,
    [Number] [varchar](17) NOT NULL,
    [TrustNumber] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [NumberType] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [legacy_number] [varchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO


USE [PHD]
/****** Object:  Index [TrustNoClustered]    Script Date: 03/06/2013 14:47:57 ******/
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [TrustNoClustered] ON [migration].[PatScope] 
(
    [TrustNumber] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


USE [PHD]
/****** Object:  Index [TrustNo]    Script Date: 03/06/2013 14:47:57 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [TrustNo] ON [migration].[PatScope] 
(
    [TrustNumber] ASC,
    [Number] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


USE [PHD]
/****** Object:  Index [TrustNumber_legacy_lookup]    Script Date: 03/06/2013 14:47:57 ******/
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [TrustNumber_legacy_lookup] ON [migration].[PatScope] 
(
    [TrustNumber] ASC,
    [legacy_number] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Check out the query plan.  Is it using the indexes you expect?  Check fragmentation.   Even if you are sure the value is not the same I would still do the <> as Matt suggested.  And I don't see an index on a.patient_pas_no.

Comment: @Blam the index on a.patient_pas_no is at the very bottom of the first code block. I missed it at first too.

Comment: @MattBusche you are correct

Comment: index on patient_pas_no is there, but hiding down at the bottom!

Comment: heh :) Cheers for other suggestions. 
I'll try the <> - I'd excluded this as I assumed it would slow things down seeing as we want every row found to update - do you know why this might improve things?

I didn't spot anything obvious in the query plan, but I should have paid more attention. I'm waiting for the query to run and kick out hte plan again, I'll see what that has to say. Thanks

Comment: The most obvious thing in the query plan is that index [patscope].[TrustNumber_legacy_lookup] is being used by a seek process - it's used in a scan process followed by a hash match and a sort.
The scan and Hash match take up 78% of query cost.
[test_hdm_rtt].[patient_pas_no] is being used in an index seek. Is there a way to force this (or might this be the correct behaviour in this case?)

Comment: Did you check fragmentation?  Yes with a hint you can force the use of an index.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx

Comment: Sorry, yes, meant to say - fragmentation is low.

Comment: Thanks - aware you can force use of index, but as far as I know (and seems confirmed looking at the 2005 version of that page) you can't force specifically seek or scan on 2005.

Comment: Have you checked if there is a trigger on the table.

Comment: Thanks - yes no trigger on the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show Execution Plan & see if the plan uses indexes.  If it doesn't,  you can force it to use a particular index:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO

update test_HDM_RTT
set patient_district_no = b.legacy_number
from test_HDM_RTT a
inner join PHD.migration.PatScope b WITH (INDEX(TrustNumber_legacy_lookup))
on a.patient_pas_no = b.TrustNumber
where a.patient_district_no <> b.legacy_number
```

You'll want to see if you need to force an index on `test_HDM_RTT` instead because it looks like it's already going to do an index scan of `TrustNumber_legacy_lookup` to get its data.

Answer (score 3):

personally, I would only update if the value is not the same as existing. That should speed up the query

```
update test_HDM_RTT
set patient_district_no = b.legacy_number
from test_HDM_RTT a
 inner join PHD.migration.PatScope b
 on a.patient_pas_no = b.TrustNumber
where a.patient_district_no <> b.legacy_number
```

I would also check out the `EXPLAIN` results (`ctrl + l`) your query may be using the wrong index.

Comment: Thanks, and I agree - I would also ordinarily. In this case though we know for certain that if a value is found in patscope, it won't be the same as the value in the table.

Comment: The problem with `where a.patient_district_no <> b.legacy_number` is that you'll miss out on `NULL` values - comparisons involving `NULL` return `NULL` unless you've `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` before executing the update.